# Find matching key-value pairs of two dictionaries

Tags: python

What will be the most efficient way to check if key-value pair of one dictionary is present in other dictionary as well.
 Suppose if I have two dictionaries as **dict1** and **dict2** and these two dictionaries have some of the key-value pairs in common. I want to find those and print them. What would be the most efficient way to do this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

one way would be:

```
d_inter = dict([k, v for k, v in dict1.iteritems() if k in dict2 and dict2[k] == v])
```

the other:

```
d_inter = dict(set(d1.iteritems()).intersection(d2.iteritems()))
```

I'm not sure which one would be more efficient, so let's compare both of them:

### 1. Solution with iteration through dicts:

- we parse all keys of dict1: `for k,v in dict1.iteritems()` -> `O(n)`
- then we check whether the key is in dict2, `if k in dict2 and dict2[k] == v` -> O(m)

which makes it a global worst case complexity of `O(n+m)` -> `O(n)`

### 2. Solution with `set`s:

if we assume that converting a `dict` into a set is `O(n)`:

- we parse all items of d1 to create the first set `set(d1.iteritems())` -> `O(n)`
- we parse all items of d2 to create the second set `set(d2.iteritems())` -> `O(m)`
- we get the intersetion of both which is `O(min(len(s), len(t))` on average or `O(n * m)` in worst case

which makes it a global worst case complexity of `O(2n*n*m)` which can be considered as O(`n^3`) for same sized dicts: then solution 1. is best

if we assume that converting a `dict` into a set is `O(1)` (constant time)

the average is `O(min(n,m))` and the worst case is `O(n*m)`, then solution #1 is best on worst case scenario, but solution #2 is best on average case scenario because `O(n+m) > O(min(n,m))`.

In conclusion, the solution you choose will depend on your dataset and the measurements you'll make! ;-)

N.B.: I took [there](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set) the complexity of the set().

N.B.2: for the solution #1 make always the smallest dict as `dict2` and for solution #2 the smallest dict as `dict1`.

---

N.B.2016: This solution was written for **python2**. Here's the changes needed to make it **python3** ready:

- replace `iteritems()` with `items()` ;
- you could also use the newer dict comprehension syntax: `{[k, v for … == v]}` ;
- as `d.items()` returns `dict_items` which is not hashable anymore, you'd have to use a `frozenset()` instead `{frozenset(d1.items()).intersection(d2.items())}`.

Comment: On my local tests, comparison: `2.86 us per loop` and set: `2.06 us per loop`. So `set` is better (at least for small dictionaries). +1 `set + iteritems` usage

Comment: @FallenAngel: Thank you for the statistics!

Comment: You can speed up your first approach by using `k in dict2` instead; in Python 2, `k in dict2.keys()` first creates a list and then has to scan through it.

Comment: ...which adds an unnecessary `O(m)` in the algorithm. @DSM good to know, I always though both were equivalent, and thus preferred to use the `.keys()` as "explicit is better than implicit" :-)

Comment: @zmo: This works absolutely fine. But whenever I have a key whose value is of type list, it throws an exception as : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Please suggest what should I do in such situations.

Comment: it's because you can't use a list as a key! The lists are mutable per design, and thus it's impossible to compute a hash for key comparison. If you really need some kind of list as a key (which is a design choice you really need to think twice before implementing), you'd better use a `tuple()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What about...

```
matching_dict_values = {}
for key in dict1.keys():
    if key in dict2.keys():
        if dict1[key] == dict2[key]:
            matching_dict_values[key]=dict1[key]
```

Comment: which is the same thing as my solution #1, but not as a one liner.

Comment: do you know if one is more efficient than the other?

Comment: what do you mean? Yes, I do, and actually my solution #1 is better than your solution, because I'm using `.iteritems()` and I followed @DSM's advice not to use `.keys()`. cf my answer for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd need anything fancier than this:

```
if all([testKey in dict1, testKey in dict2]) and dict1[testKey] == dict2[testKey]:
```

We don't have to worry about a `KeyError` because the boolean test will fail before the `and` (do a value which correlates to a key that isn't in one of them will never get tested)

So to get your full list common key-value pairs you could do this:

```
for testKey in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys()):
    if all([testKey in dict1, testKey in dict2]) and dict1[testKey] == dict2[testKey]:
        commonDict[testKey] = dict1[testKey]
```

Comment: he wants the intersection of two dicts, not whether a given key is in both dicts. So to apply your solution to his problem, you'd tell him to do a `for testKey in dict1.keys()+dict2.keys(): ...`?!

Comment: @zmo, It seemed to me that the real problem here was finding if a key-value pair is common to both, and that everything after that would be fairly easy, but I'll update to get a full list of common pairs

Comment: even though your problem answers the question, it is not efficient at all, as it implies a constant `O(n*m*(n+m))` which is `O(n3)` in worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Update to @zmo's answer

Solution 1:

```
d_inter = {k:v for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2 and dict2[k] == v}
```

Solution 2:

```
d_inter = dict(set(dict1.items()).intersection(dict2.items()))
```